# how to send pushwoosh notification with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, push-notification, pushwoosh

I've studied the pushwoosh romote api,the basic process to send a notification is to post a piece of JSON data to http://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/createMessage  and to be specific,the data will be packaged in the format like

```
 {'application' : PW_APPLICATION,
    'auth'      : PW_AUTH,
    'notifications':{
           'send_date' : 'now',
           'content'   : 'test',
           'data'      : {
                'custom' : 'json data'
            },
           'link' : 'http://pushwoosh.com/'
     }
 }
```

the pushwoosh guide lists serveral of sample codes in Java,PHP,Ruby and so on.I am quite confused that pushwoosh doesn't provide  the nodejs version,so I have to  carry it out by myself.I use the 'http' module to send the request and the parameters and part of main codes is shown below

```
var bodyArgs = 
{'application' : PW_APPLICATION,
    'auth'      : PW_AUTH,
    'notifications':{
           'send_date' : 'now',
           'content'   : 'test',
           'data'      : {
                'custom' : 'json data'
            },
           'link' : 'http://pushwoosh.com/'
     }
 }

var bodyArgsArray = [];
for (var i in bodyArgs) {
    if (bodyArgs.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        if(typeof bodyArgs[i] == 'object'){
            bodyArgsArray.push(i + '=' + (JSON.stringify(bodyArgs[i])));
        }else{
            bodyArgsArray.push(i + '=' + (bodyArgs[i]));
        }
    }
}
var options = {
    host: 'cp.pushwoosh.com',
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/json/1.3/createMessage',
    headers: {'Content-Length': bodyStr.length,
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
}
var req = http.request(options, function (res){...});
```

unfortunately,I get the malformed response

```
[syntax error at end of input]
```

if the request is processed successfully, the correct response shoule be

```
{
    "status_code":200,
    "status_message":"OK",
    "response": {
        "Messages":["{Notification code}", "{Notification code}", ...]
    }  
}
```

I got a great desire to figure out the correct request format.I will be pretty appreciate  of someone's nodejs version if possible!

And the pushwoosh remote-api-guide website is

https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/pushwoosh-push-notification-remote-api/

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to get this working.  You were really close

{
   "request":{
      "application":"APPLICATION_CODE",
      "applications_group":"GROUP_CODE",       // Optional. Can be used instead of "application"
      "auth":"api_access_token",
      "notifications":[]
}}

So the thing that got left off is that you need to wrap your json request in a object called "request" as you can see above. I am actually in the process of writing a node module to use pushwoosh.  I thought I would post this in case anyone is looking for the answer.  I will post the npm module name once I finish it but if you really want to get it working now that is all you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i have written a [node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pushwoosh-client) to send push notifications to mobile devices with Pushwoosh API

Comment: nluo, what about tags to limit sends...?

Comment: @ChrisH I believe you could just do tags inside options param

Comment: much appreciated. I've been tinkering and got that working. So sorry I didn't come back and edit/delete my comment. Their tag mechanism works ok, if perhaps a bit verbose and repetitious. Thanks!